# pdfpages-PDF appears in background of pgfplots-plot

Tags: pgfplots, pdfpages, tikz-external

I'm using pgfplots with the externalize feature, which creates external pdfs for all my plots.
But there seems to be a strange interaction with pdfpages when externalize is used.
The pdf I'm including appears in the backgrounds of my plots:
[image: Plot with pgfplots. My frontpage that is included via pdfpages appears in the background]
There is no error message when typesetting the whole ordeal.

I include pgfplots with

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotstableset{col sep=comma}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external} 
\tikzexternalize[optimize=false, prefix=external/, optimize command away=\includepdf]
```

You can see, I already tried something with `optimize command away=\includepdf` but to no avail.

Pdfpages simply by

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}
```

The titlepage:

```
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty}},offset=0cm 0cm]{TitlePageMasterarbeitIME.pdf}
```

I couldn't find an answer to this by googling so maybe one of you has experienced something similiar and knows a way to work around this problem.

Thanks in advance

**Edit: MWE:**
My PDF file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6t1jottxcjkmn1r/TitlePageMasterarbeitIME.pdf?dl=1)

```
\documentclass[DIV12,a4paper,headsepline,titlepage,ngerman]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external} 
\tikzexternalize[optimize=false, prefix=external/, optimize command away=\includepdf]

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty}},offset=0cm 0cm]{TitlePageMasterarbeitIME.pdf}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    name=VentileMassenstromAusschnitt,
    width=0.87\textwidth, % Scale the plot to \linewidth
    minor y tick num = 1,
    minor x tick num = 1,
    scale only axis,
    grid=both, 
    grid style={dashed,gray!30},
    ]
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0)
                        (5,5)}; 
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a fully compilable minimal example that the rest of us can copy and test. When people have to add stuff to make it compile, they are less likely to help

Comment: Hey, thanks for your input. I try to create one that shows the problem.

Comment: Very curious: it seems that `\includepdf` remembers forever to add the title page.

Comment: yeah, it seems as if it may be a problem in pdlatex itself, which would make fixing it harder...

Comment: I've encountered exactly the same problem, and the solution given here has worked, but only when I've put `\tikzexternalenable` before, and `\tikzexternaldisable` after the `\includepdf` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the title page made its way into the externalized figure (I opened it and saw it there).

In order to solve it, we have to disable the title page during the image externalization.

In fact, changing `optimize=false` to `optimize=true` does this -- and the pdf appears to be fine. If there is a particular reason for `optimize=false`? This key actually disables your carefully placed `optimize command away=\includepdf`.
If you really need `optimize=false`, you could still use `\tikzifexternalizing{<true case>}{<false case>}` in order to suppress the title page.

```
\documentclass[DIV12,a4paper,headsepline,titlepage,ngerman]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external} 
\tikzexternalize[optimize=true, optimize command away=\includepdf]

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty}},offset=0cm 0cm]{TitlePageMasterarbeitIME.pdf}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    name=VentileMassenstromAusschnitt,
    width=0.87\textwidth, % Scale the plot to \linewidth
    minor y tick num = 1,
    minor x tick num = 1,
    scale only axis,
    grid=both, 
    grid style={dashed,gray!30},
    ]
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0)
                        (5,5)}; 
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah I see. It was a leftover from when i had other troubles with externalizing the plots.
Your solution works like a charm.
Thank you!